# kinect camera with 32-bit ubuntu

Tags: slam, rgbd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
Can kinect camera be connected to ubuntu 32-bit for RGBDSLAM package? I'm using ubuntu 11.10 32-bit os. Its dual boot along with windows7 64-bit. I installed with 32-bit ubuntu cd accidently and working on it. I wanted to confirm before buying kinect, can i use the openni driver for kinect and perform rgbdslam or should i change to 64-bit ubuntu 11.10?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31606/kinect-camera-with-32-bit-ubuntu/) by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-04-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on 2012-04-11**:
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, Kinect works perfectly with rgbdslam. I tested it with ROS Electric from binary package. Ubuntu 11.04 and 11.10, 32-bit.

---

Originally posted by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) with karma: 546 on 2012-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3